# Probability that the density is equal to 0

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable taking values in $\mathbb{R}$, with density $f$ . Prove that $P(f(X)=0)=0$ . Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Use the definition: let $A=\{f(X)=0\}$ and $B=\{x\mid f(x)=0\}$, then $A=\{X\in B\}$ hence $$P(A)=\int_AdP=\int_Bf(x)dx=\ldots$$

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of the pdf is

$$P(X\in A)=\int_A f(x)\ dx.$$

Then

$$P(f(X)=0)=P(X\in \{f(x)=0\})=\int_{\{f(x)=0\}}f(x)\ dx=???$$